# strange silent crash in python with combination of: OSX, requests, sqlite3, multiprocessing

Tags: python, macos, sqlite, multiprocessing, python-requests

Chaps,

bizarre behaviour I've come across that I don't know how to fix. If I have the following code:

```
import requests, multiprocessing, sqlite3

requests.get( "http://www.google.com" )
def fn():
  sqlite3.connect( "db" )
  print "this is never printed"

proc = multiprocessing.Process( target = fn )
proc.start()
proc.join()
```

And I run it on OS X Yosemite, The subprocess falls over during the sqlite3 connect command, and the print statement is never executed. I don't see any errors or any signs of anything else going wrong.

When I remove the `requests.get` statement, it starts working again.

Seems to work fine on Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "falls over"?  If it ends with no output then run (in bash) `ulimit -c unlimited` then run your code - it might produce a `core` dump file.

Comment: Hi cdarke, thanks for the help! I wasn't able to make it produce any sort of file by using the commands you provided. However, I was previously running it inside a virtualenv. I deactivated my virtualenv and ran it against my global python binary and I got a `python quite unexpectedly` error, along with the following dump of information: http://pastebin.com/vdiQFT8j

I hope thats sufficient information?

Comment: OK, a SIGSEGV is an invalid address - probably the most common form of crash.  It is *usually* caused by an invalid pointer in C or C++ code.  Are you trying to run a module on OS X that comes from elsewhere, like Ubuntu? Or maybe mixing 32-bit and 64-bit?

Comment: The crash is occurring in libdispatch.dylib (sqlite), which we could probably have guessed, in a fork handler.  The invalid address is 0x110, which is far too low, and an invalid address.

Answer (score 1):

Chaps,

this isn't a 100% solution, but to anyone else struggling with this,

switching to the `httplib2` library instead of `requests` seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Mac OS X/Python bug. To work around it, run the following code before calling multiprocessing.Process: `sqlite3.connect(":memory:").close()`. See: http://bugs.python.org/issue27126

Comment: Mate you absolute legend!! Thanks for this

Comment: Should just add, that this didn't 100% work out for me in the end. It reduced crashed by about 90%, but I was still getting random processes occasionally falling over... What we ended up doing was installing python from python.org and using that instead of the standard OS X python.